# quadratic equation solver fails to get result in Java

Tags: java, quadratic

I have code that is supposed to solve a quadratic equation but yields NaN as a result.

I've looked around for 2 days now and I can't find a solution. Any and all advice will be more than appreciated!

```
package quadratic;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Formlua {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter value of A ");
        double a = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter value of B ");
        double b = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("enter value of C ");    
        double c = input.nextDouble();
        double four = 4;
        double square = Math.sqrt(b* b - 4 * a * c );

        double root1 = (-b + square) / (2*a);

        double root2 = (-b - square) / (2*a);   
        System.out.println("The answer is " + root1 + "and" + root2);

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue? y/n");

        String user = input.toString();
        if(user.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your values of `a`, `b`, and `c`?  Is `b* b - 4 * a * c` negative?

Comment: abc and the number the user inputs. This corresponds to the variable in the quadratic equation. And no its not negative just the -b at the begging of the equation.      (-b[+or-] sqrt(b^2-4ac)/2a  in English negative b plus or minus square root b squared minus 4ac over 2 a

Answer (score 6):

This code:

```
Math.sqrt(b* b - 4 * a * c );
```

can result in `NaN` ("not a number").

If the value of `b* b - 4 * a * c` is negative, there are solutions only in complex numbers (but not in double data type)

There should be a condition

```
if (b* b - 4 * a * c<0) {
    System.out.println("There is no solution in real numbers");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The most likely cause of the problem is Math.sqrt(b*b - 4 * a * c). or one of your input values is NaN (probably not the cause in this situation).

There are two special cases:
b *b < 4 * a * c
and a = 0

if b * b < 4 * a * c your answer is in the complex plane (specifically, not a real number).
if a = 0 then you actually just have a linear equation.

you could try the following code:

```
package quadratic;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Formlua {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter value of A ");
    double a = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("enter value of B ");
    double b = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("enter value of C ");    
    double c = input.nextDouble();

    if (a == 0){
      // 0 = 0*x*x + b*x + c  ==> x = -c/b
      System.out.println("X = " + Double.toString(-c/b));
    } else {
      double inner = b * b - 4 * a * c;
      if (inner < 0){
        inner = -inner;
        inner = Math.sqrt(inner);
        System.out.println("X = " + Double.toString(-b) + " + " + Double.toString(inner) + "i")
        System.out.println("  = " + Double.toString(-b) + " - " + Double.toString(inner) + "i");
      } else {
         inner = Math.sqrt(inner);
           System.out.println("X = " + Double.toString(-b));
         if (inner == 0){
         } else {
           System.out.println("X = " + Double.toString(-b + inner));
           System.out.println("X = " + Double.toString(-b - inner));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This lets your user input any double values and recieve an answer.

Comment: Seems to do the trick. The code is a bit advance for my noob brain at least at the moment. It steal leaves me with an unfinished answer like the doubleofstring + number i. Is there away to just change var type of OP code to allow imaginary numbers? oh and thanks for the time you took to help me out! Really appreciated!

Comment: I don't know any standard java way to perform math with complex numbers. You could create your own complex numbers class. Here's someone's attempt at doing just that.  https://www.math.ksu.edu/~bennett/jomacg/c.html. In the end though, you'll still end up with two parts, a real part and an imaginary part.

Comment: Alright ill look into that when i get some sleep but thanks for the links and helping me out!

Comment: Nice complex solver +1 ;) (`Math.abs` in your code is redundant)

Comment: You're Right. I don't know why I thought I needed it.